# Tomcat not accepting JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm trying to run Tomcat on the latest jdk and, after setting the path in /etc/proile, /etc/environment, etc/default/tomcat8, and a couple of other places, when I go to fire up Tomcat, it says:

```
     /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /var/lib/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java: not found
```

The reply for `echo $JAVA_HOME` is:

```
    /var/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_71/
```

and the reply for `java -version` is:

```
    java version "1.8.0_71"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

What am I missing, please?

Comment: So what happens if you run `which java`?

Comment: Where does the wrong path (/var/lib/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java) come from ?

Comment: I suspect 2 jdks are running. May be one is pre-installed in your machine. Find it. Also make sure you set TOMCAT_HOME and CLASSPATH accurately

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that like a `sudo`:

```
   sudo su vi /var/bash.bashrc
```

And copy following:

```
   JAVA_HOME=/var/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_71
   export JAVA_HOME
   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   export PATH
```